# Software to evaluate *.gpx files

Tags: mountain-bike, gps, software

I record my mountain bike tours using my Android mobile. Now I want to evaluate the tours. Currently I'm using [MyTourbook](http://mytourbook.sourceforge.net/). This would be a great software, but it has two major drawbacks: The height is calculate very roughly and the time in motion calculation isn't correct too. That's why I'm looking for a new software. The software should be able to:

- Show the tour on a map
- Show me the distance, the elevation, the average and max speed and the time of each tour
- A little bit of statistics, so that I can see how many meters I've done in a year, a month, etc.

Any recommendations? It should be for windows.

Comment: If you want a non-website solution, you definitely need to include information about your computer.  Windows? Mac? Linux? http://www.superuser.com/?

Comment: Yes you're right, I updated my answer. I'm note sure if it is better located on super user, but maybe I should move there.

Comment: GPS are notoriously bad at calculating z coordinates.  Even if you find a program where the elevation profile produced looks better... all z coordinates should remain suspect.  These will routinely fall outside of the stated horizontal accuracy of whatever unit you are using.  I haven't used MyTourBook so I don't know how rough "roughly" is, but I would urge caution in analyzing GPS-produced elevation data in any case.

Comment: @DC_CARR I can agree, but for example today I made a tour which I know is exactly 460 meters, because it starts at my frontdoor, goes just straight up and ends 460 meter above at a landmark. I recorded it with my phone (MyTrack) and the statistic in this app saido 480 meters. This is in my opinion not too bad, but then I imported it into MyTourbook and I get a value of 590 meters. That is really way to much. Particularly because I know I could be done better.

Comment: @Roflcopter - You may be expecting too much accuracy of GPS.

Comment: @Roflcopter - You can expect the measurement to be accurate within 10 m horizontally and 16 m vertically with a basic GPS. See http://www.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/edu/geod/gps/gps13_e.php. A differential measurement will do better, but you need two receivers (at different locations) or a base station at a known location.

Comment: I assume you've gone through the GPX resources list here http://www.topografix.com/gpx_resources.asp and nothing suits you?? It looks to me at first glance as though there should be something there, and there are communities for the few that I checked.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I decided to buy a real GPS device. This device does not only use GPS to calculate the height, but is supported by a barometer. I tested it yesterday an the height calculation is now very accurate as expected. On various points of my tour I verified the height calculation and it was never more than 10 meters (mostly 5 meters) wrong.

Comment: @freiheit @Neil Fein @moz @DC_CARR @Wayne Johnston forgot to notify you ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software about cycling is off topic.  Please ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and use the tag for cycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if a web "software" (aka website) is in your needs, but I recommend GPSIES: http://www.gpsies.com/convert.do

Item 1 of your list is for sure;
Item 2 not sure if it will be at such fine grain;
Item 3 yes, maybe not in such detail.

Even if not for this need the link is usefull and free, I use it a lot (I have nothing to do with this site I just like it).

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer an offline solution... never know what happens if the site goes down... want risk to loose my tours.

Comment: Good point. Appart from this site I have no other suggestion :(